# new textarea onfocus is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this interface : 
[image]

When the "Add Another One" button is clicked, i will have to add another interface that looks the same as this one, so that the whole interface would look something like this : 
[image] 
I had the attribute onfocus for the textarea in order to clear it content when in focus, and it is working prefectly, this is the code for it :

```
<textarea name="educationDescription1" id="educationDescription1" rows="5" cols="33" onfocus="clearContents(this);">Describe your studying experience in a couple of sentences.</textarea>
```

Now I'm having problems doing the same for the created textarea, although i have used the same syntax! This is the code used for creating the new text area :

```
var node6 = document.createElement("textarea");
node6.rows="5";
node6.cols="33";
node6.onfocus="clearContents(this);";
node6.value="Describe your working experience in a couple of sentences.";
node6.name="experienceDescription"+experiences;
node6.id="experienceDescription"+experiences;
```

Any idea what could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `node6.onfocus` , `onfocus` needs a function reference. You are assigning a string. It should be something like,

```
node6.onfocus=function(){clearContents(this);};
```

Or you can use `addeventListner` function

```
node6.addEventListener('onfocus',function(){clearContents(this);});
```

Or if you want to add onfocus into the html you have to create a new attribute and set it like this.

```
var attr = document.createAttribute('onfocus');
attr.value="clearContents(this)";
node6.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
node6.onfocus="clearContents(this);";
```

Should be replaced by this:

```
node6.onfocus=function(){clearContents(this);};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to use `placeholder` attribute instead of `onfocus`.
If you use `onfocus`, the textarea would be cleared everytime the user make a focus on it even after the user input valid data.

The code to set `placeholder` with jQuery could be something like this:

```
var node6 = $("<textarea></textarea>");
...
node6.attr('placeholder','Describe your working ...');
```

Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/j687tg80/2/

Hope this helps.